# Serverside validation framework for the models(using data annotations) in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have so many classes in Models used as entities for my application.
I'm using data annotations for the model attributes as below:

```
    [Required]
    [DataMember]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
```

I do not want to use data annotation for each n every model.
I want to have a generic validation framework which will have a method that can be used to validate all the properties in my model class.

Has anyone used such a generic type of validation to do server side validations, please help?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure I understand. If you post back your models, the `DefaultModelBinder` does the server side validation on all your properties. What more do you need?

Comment: I need a kind of ASP.NET MVC fluent validation framework
http://fluentmvc.codeplex.com/